# print statement only when the condition is CONSECUTIVELY met 3 times in a row

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently making a guessing game where user can get a congrats statement if they guess correctly 3 times in a row or a hint statement if they guesses incorrectly 3 times in a row. If user makes two correct guesses and one incorrect guess the count will reset and vice versa for incorrect guesses. the goal is for the right/wrong guess to be 3 times in a row for the statement to print

Here is what I have

```py
count = 0

rightGuess = 0

wrongGuess = 0

die1 = random.randint(1,6)



guess = int(input('Enter guess: '))

if guess == die1:
     
rightGuess += 1
     
print('Good job')
     
     if rightGuess == 3:
          print('You guessed three times in a row!')


if guess != die1:
      
wrongGuess += 1
      
print('Uh oh wrong answer')
     
      if wrongGuess == 3:
           print("Hint: issa number :)")
```

This works but it displays the text whenever the user reaches 3 wrong or right guesses even if it's not in a row. Please help

Comment: Formatting of your question is broken. Fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to reset the opposite variable to 0 when incrementing either of them.

```py
count = 0
consecutiveRightGuess = 0
consecutiveWrongGuess = 0
die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
guess = int(input('Enter guess: '))

if guess == die1:
    consecutiveWrongGuess = 0
    consecutiveRightGuess += 1
    print('Good job')
    if consecutiveRightGuess == 3:
        print('You guessed three times in a row!')

if guess != die1:
    consecutiveRightGuess = 0
    consecutiveWrongGuess += 1
    print('Uh oh wrong answer')
    if consecutiveWrongGuess == 3:
        print("Hint: issa number :)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the rightGuess variable using `rightGuess = 0` when you add 1 to the wrongGuess variable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it like this only using one variable for counting guesses:

```
import random

count = 0

while True:
    die1 = random.randint(1,6)

    guess = int(input("Enter guess: "))

    if guess == die1:
        count = count + 1 if count >= 0 else 1
        print('Good job')

    if guess != die1:
        print('Uh oh wrong answer')
        count = count - 1 if count <= 0 else -1

    if count == 3:
        print('You guessed three times in a row!')
        break

    if count == -3:
        print("Hint: issa number :)")
        break
```